# Surjective Homomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}$ -> pre-image has normal Subgroup of index n

Tags: group-theory

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of Group $G$ and $\phi: G/N \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ a surjective homomorphism. I have to prove, that for every positve integer $n\in \mathbb{N}$ exists a normal subgroup $U$ in  $G$ with index $n$.

I thought of this: The preimage of a normal subgroup under a surjective homomorphism is a normal subgroup. So if $\phi^{-1}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ with $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ a normal subgroup von $\mathbb{Z}$ with index $n$, would have index $n$ in $G/N$, i'm done by using the homomorphism law. The question is, can i show this somehow? I got no idea.

Comment: You need to pull that subgroup back to $G$, not just $G/N$.

Comment: $N$ has no role; if you have $\phi\colon G/N\to\mathbb{Z}$ you also have $\phi'\colon G\to\mathbb{Z}$ (compose $\phi$ with the projection).

Comment: Yeah i got the relation between $\phi$ and $\phi'$. But im still not sure, if $\phi^{-1}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ has index $n$. I got no idea to prove this, or even if its fullfilled.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the chain of homomorphisms
$$
G\xrightarrow{\pi}G/N\xrightarrow{\varphi}\mathbb{Z}
\xrightarrow{p_n}\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}
$$
where $\varphi_n=p_n\circ\varphi\circ\pi$ is surjective. Then consider the induced homomorphism
$$
G/\ker\varphi_n\to\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}
$$
What does it mean that a normal subgroup $K$ of $G$ has index $n$? That the quotient group $G/K$ has $n$ elements.

So, what can we say about $\ker\varphi_n$? The answer is in the homomorphism theorem: the induced homomorphism $G/\ker\varphi_n\to\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is injective by construction and also surjective because $\varphi_n$ is surjective. So it is an isomorphism and, since $|\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}|=n$, $\ker\varphi_n$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ of index $n$ (and containing $N$).

Comment: It is $ker(\pi)=N$, $g ker(\pi)=ker(\phi)$, $ker(p_{n})=n\mathbb{Z}$.  It is $ker(\phi_{n})=ker(p_{n}\phi\pi)=\pi^{-1}(\phi^{-1}(ker(p_{n}))$, but what is $\phi^{-1}(ker(p_{n}))$?

Comment: Edit: If normal subgroup $K$ of $G$ has index $n$, then the quotient Group $G/K$ has index $n$.

Comment: @zitoxas You don't need to compute anything; the condition about the index is that $[G:K]=n$ if and only if $|G/K|=n$.

Comment: Ah i got it. Thank you so much